# Is there an advantage to using the is operator instead of == in CoffeeScript

Tags: coffeescript

Other than to just be using a Coffeescript language feature, is there any advantage to using the `is` operator instead of `==`?

According to the [documentation](http://coffeescript.org/#operators) they both compile down to `===`.

I ask because it came up during a code review and I'm thinking it would be a bad idea for us, as a C#/.NET company on the server side to enforce the use of `is` for comparing when its meaning is completely different in C# (determining whether an object is a given type).

If there is an advantage to it though, I don't want to push back.

Comment: I suppose if you use `is`, `isnt`, and `not` then you have to remember that `isnt` and `is not` are completely different. I'm a math guy originally so I like my symbols and use `==`, `!=`, `&&`, `||`, and `!` rather than their pretend-English "word" versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like you said, there's no functional difference. But one advantage is that it's easier for a developer to remember that `is` compiles to something else than it is to remember that `==` compiles to something else, since `==` is an actual JavaScript operator and `is` is not.

Comment: Good point, I don't think any of us on our team are experienced enough to know when to we must use `==` vs `===` so it wasn't something I had considered.